# Working with URL query Strings in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am new to working with ASP.NET and want to find the best way to work with URL query strings.

I can get the current value of a URL query string by using `Request.QueryString["UrlKey"]`, but can I actually modify the URL with code, without doing a form `GET` submission?

If the user is landing on the page for the first time, what is the easiest way to programmatically create the `?UrlKey=value` through the `Page_load` method? Or am I better of doing this with Javascript or building a redirect Like: `string redirect = "www.mysite.com?" + MyKey + "=" + MyValue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do this:

```
string redirect = "www.mysite.com?mykey=" + MyValue.ToString();
Response.Redirect(redirect);
```

Comment: Yes - I knew it would be simple! Is this the best way to manage the URL in a ASP.NET Ajax application? For instance, I am using updatepanel and scriptmanager. I have two "pager" buttons each linked to two separate click handlers. So I should build the URL I want in the click handlers?

Comment: I'm not much more experience with ASP.Net development than you are.  So I can't really say what the best practice is.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no standard way to go from a key-value pair to a query string. However, you can do it yourself rather trivially, especially if you use LINQ.

Either way, please use [HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode.aspx) on both the key and value to avoid generating corrupt URLs. If you are doing it in JavaScript, see [encodeURIComponent](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/).