# Redirect Pages after Inserting Data in ASP.NET /C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, postback, response.redirect

Im made a webform that insert data to the database. When the insert button was clicked, the codes for inserting data is triggered and after successfully inserting data, It redirects to other page that says "Data Inserted Successfully".
It was like this...

INSERT PAGE.....

```
if (CodeClass.InsertData(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, Gender) == true)
     {
         String A = "InsertSuccess";

          Response.Redirect("OtherPage.aspx?&lnk=" + A);
     }
```

OTHER PAGE....

```
   String link = null;
            link = Request.QueryString["lnk"];
            if (link == "InsertSuccess")
            {
                txtLabel.Text = "Record inserted succesfully!";

            }
```

My problem is when I access the OTHER PAGE even I did not use the insert page..I am getting same results. Lets say I typed ..http://localhost:8672/OtherPage.aspx?&lnk=InsertSuccess in the address bar..I am getting "Record inserted succesfully!" label. I want the OTHER PAGE to never show "Record inserted succesfully!" message when I actually did not insert something but rather just access it through the browser's address bar.

Comment: Why do you even want to redirect to another page? If you only want to show a status-message, just add a Label to your Form with the attribute Visible set to false. After inserting the data you set your Label text, make it visible and make your insert-form invisible. This way you'll save a whole page just for one little message.

Comment: Thanks for the very practical suggestion but my real purpose of this is how can I ensure that the page was loaded through the website redirect and not by directly visiting a link. Useful suggestion though :)

Answer (score 2):

you may use Session variable  to store updated status and then check if it is available in otherpage.aspx,update textbox and reset it.

Insert Page

```
if (CodeClass.InsertData(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, Gender) == true)
     {
          Session["status"]="InsertSuccess";


          Response.Redirect("OtherPage.aspx");
     }
}
```

Other Page

```
if (Session["status"]!=null)
        {
            txtLabel.Text = "Record inserted succesfully!";
            Session["status"]=null; 

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for what I see you dont want to get the message just by typing "http://localhost:8672/OtherPage.aspx&lnk=InsertSuccess" in the address bar, then I would recommend you that instead of passing a string with a flag you should pass the record ID, then on your other page you should check that your record ID really exist on your table.

For that I hope that you are working with  ID as a GUID type.

You'll have something like this:

"http://localhost:8672/OtherPage.aspx&lnk=BBB5259E-F5A3-4271-ABC8-D95A00BE9770"

Otherwise it would be too easy to remember an int ID.

Comment: This approach is very useful when you are working with Windows Azure where you can have several instances and you need to keep your variables on a perdurable storage, but for what I see with a session variable is good enough.

Comment: oic
Im still new to asp.net
Perhaps I'll be working on it for sometime :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should change your querystring.

```
    Response.Redirect("OtherPage.aspx?&lnk=" + A);
```

Should be:

```
    Response.Redirect("OtherPage.aspx?lnk=" + A);
```

The '&' sign when not encoded are treated as a parameter separator.

```
    Response.Redirect("OtherPage.aspx?lnk=" + A + "&secondParam=someValue");
```

As requested by comment:
See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330447/working-with-url-query-strings-in-asp-net)

[MSDN HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

[.NET Slave - Working with query strings](http://madskristensen.net/post/Working-with-query-strings.aspx)

and the [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) might be handy sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for this post.Actually I have just a very little idea on working with querystrings. I just copied it from other project. This is very helpful! May I ask some links about working with this?
I am really totally new to asp.net
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (CodeClass.InsertData(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, Gender) == true)
     {
       HttpContext.Current.Items["A"]= "Inserted Successfully";

          Server.Transfer("OtherPage.aspx);
     }



string ContextData =(string) HttpContext.Current.Items["A"];

if(!string.Empty(ContextData))
{  
Label1.Text = ContextData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you fix your URL and remove the "&" after the "?" .. You have to remove the "&"

Have you thought about the browser cache? sometimes cache can do this and I have struggled with an issue similar to yours because of the cache settings.

Comment: Im still totally new to asp.net. This is seems interesting! browser cache..I think Ill be working on this on the future.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add this script after succeed inserted code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Success", "setInterval(function(){location.href='Default.aspx';},3000);", true);
```

Comment: It would help to have more explanation about why this code resolves the problem. Furthermore, the first sentence of your answer is incomprehensible, it would be great if you could check it.